# Sorting in descending order in java shows one element less

Tags: java

I wrote  a code to sort an array of 50 elements on descending order but the array that shows on the console has 49 elements. Can anyone help me with this?

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length-1; i++) { 
    for( int j = i+1; j<vek.length; j++) { 
        if (vek[i]<vek[j]) { 
            int temp= vek[j]; 
            vek[j]=vek[i]; 
            vek[i]=temp; 
        } 
    } 
    System.out.print(vek[i] + " "); 
}
```

Comment: please show the code you're having an issue with.

Comment: for(i=0; i<vek.length-1; i++)
  {
   for( int j = i+1; j<vek.length; j++)
   {
    
   if (vek[i]<vek[j])
   {
    int temp= vek[j];
    vek[j]=vek[i];
    vek[i]=temp;
            }
  
   }
   System.out.print(vek[i] + " ");
   
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using bubble sorting. This algorithms compares pairs of elements where first element is set by outer loop, second by inner loop from elements *after* currently selected first element. It makes sense to let outer loop ignore last element, because for him inner loop can't select any element after it (because it is last element). So if we are talking only about sorting changing

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length-1; i++) {..}
```

to

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length; i++) { .. }
```

wouldn't make sense.

But because you also added code responsible for printing your elements inside outer loop (which iterates from `0` till `vek.length-1`) it means this loop will iterate only `length-1` times, but you have `vek.length` elements.

So you have few possible solutions

- (IMO clearest) move code responsible for printing out of code responsible for sorting (so add another loop for printing after bubble sort)

  ```
  for(i=0; i<vek.length-1; i++) { 
      for( int j = i+1; j<vek.length; j++) { 
          if (vek[i]<vek[j]) { 
              int temp= vek[j]; 
              vek[j]=vek[i]; 
              vek[i]=temp; 
          } 
      } 
      //System.out.print(vek[i] + " ");  //<--- remove this
  } 
  for(i=0; i<vek.length; i++) { // here we removed "-1"
      System.out.print(vek[i] + " ");
  }
  ```
- add code responsible for printing *last* element after sorting/printing
  `for (...){ for(...){...} print([i])} print(array[array.length-1]);`
- let your *outer* loop iterate `vek.length` times (because that is the amount of elements in array) by changing `i<vek.length-1` to `i<vek.length`. You will not need to worry about inner loop, because it will not iterate even once at last iteration of outer loop (when `i=vek.length-1` because then `j=i+1` would be equal to `j=(vek.length-1)+1=vek.length`, making `j<vek.length` condition false because of `vek.length<vek.length`).

Comment: Pshemo, nicely put

Answer (score 0):

You are only iterating until one to the end...

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length-1; i++)
```

This says "iterate from 0 to one before the length of vek, minus 1".

What you probably need is:

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length; i++)
```

By saying `i < vek.length`, you are already accounting for the fact that this is a zero-based array. Picture an array of only two elements:

1. `i` starts at 0.
2. Since `i` is less than 2, we execute the loop body.
3. `i++` makes `i` = 1.
4. Since `i` is less than 2, we execute the loop body.
5. `i++` makes `i` = 2.
6. Since `i` is equal to 2, we stop looping.

Long story short: You are introducing an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Answer (score 0):

Should it be at the very first line as below, as you want to print all elements?

```
for(i=0; i<vek.length; i++) {
```